# Hide and unhide custom block programatically drupal 9

Tags: blocks

Hello I have created a module to display a block. I would like to set the block visibity to visible and hidden in the homepage based on a condition.

like this:

edit:

```
//fetch status from database then check condition
if ($status = 1){
//make block visible
}else{
//hide block
}
```

I have searched all over the internet and could not find how to make it work.

I have a form that is used to add contents to a database and it has a checkbox to whether make the make the block visible or not.

So I would fetch the status(visible/hidden) of the block from the database and then make the block visible.

Comment: Why not create a new visibility context instead of this?

Comment: hello @Kevin thanks for your comment. Can you please give me more information about this, actually I am new to drupal.

Comment: We need more information about the condition in order to give you the best solution as in Drupal, you can do this multiple ways: in the block configuration, hooks and/or twig templates

Comment: @NicklasMandrupFrederiksen I have just updated the question do check it please

Comment: https://www.jaypan.com/tutorial/custom-drupal-block-visibility-plugins-and-condition-plugin-api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a module to display a block this usually means you implement a block plugin. Then you can add the condition to the plugin directly:

```
  protected function blockAccess(AccountInterface $account) {
    $access = $this->languageManager->isMultilingual() ? AccessResult::allowed() : AccessResult::forbidden();
    return $access->addCacheTags(['config:configurable_language_list']);
  }
```

Example from core [LanguageBlock::blockAccess()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21language%21src%21Plugin%21Block%21LanguageBlock.php/function/LanguageBlock%3A%3AblockAccess).

Comment: Thanks this worked